# i have problem after installing NetBeans on my Linux Mint it can't do anything

Tags: linux, netbeans, linux-mint

I am trying to install NetBeans 8.2 on my Linux Mint 19.1 I can't start a new project or doing anything.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to resolve it?

[image: Netbeans]

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 8.2 is working for me on Linux Mint. The most likely cause of your problem is that NetBeans 8.2 is configured to use an incompatible version of Java. To see which version of Java is being used, select **Help > About**:

[image: LinuxHelpAbout]

If you are using NetBeans 8.2 then:

- JDK 8 must be installed.
- NetBeans 8.2 must be configured to use JDK 8, as shown in the screen shot above.

As long as both conditions are met it does not matter how many other versions of Java are installed on your machine. I assume you know how to install JDK 8 (if necessary). To configure NetBeans to use JDK 8:

- Locate the file **netbeans.conf** within the **etc** directory of your NetBeans installation directory.
- **netbeans.conf** is a text file containing name/value property pairs. Open it in any text editor.
- Locate the line containing the text **netbeans_jdkhome**. If that line is commented out by the use of a leading `#` character, delete that character.
- Set the value of the property **netbeans_jdkhome** to the path to your JDK 8 installation.
- On my Linux Mint machine the entry looks like this `netbeans_jdkhome="/home/johndoe/jdk1.8.0_151"`, although you will probably be using a more recent update version of JDK 8.
- Save the changes to **netbeans.conf** and (re)start Netbeans. Everything should work now.

If you still have problems update your question with:

- A screen shot of **Help > About** like the one shown above.
- The content of the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) that was written since the most recent restart of NetBeans.